# Call this.props inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var ElementList = React.createClass({render: function() {
        var x = this.props.icon;
        return (
           {this.props.data.map(function(value,i) {return (      
                <span key={i} className={ "fa " + x } data-id={value.id} ></span>             
            )})}
    );}});
```

How can I directly use this.props.icon inside the map function. Instead of using the x variable and declaring it outside.

Comment: Check the second argument of the `Array.prototype.map` or use ES2015 arrow functions.

Comment: @downvoter please specify the reason for downvote. I did try to put the property inside map function and it did not work.

Comment: Any chance you've read my comment? (for the notes though: it was not me who downvoted)

Comment: @zerkms the one used for the key?

Comment: replaced x with i.props.icon or i.icon. both don't work.

Comment: The first comment, 4 centimeters above. It's just 15 words, none of them references to any keys or replacing anything with something else.

Answer (score 6):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
this.props.data.map((value, i) => {
  return <div key={i}>{this.props.icon}</div>
});
```

Comment: Yes, see the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use es6 arrow functions you can bind `this` to your map function...

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar'];
array.map(function() {
     //this has been passed through
}.bind(this));
```